# Session variables are sometimes "dropped" by IE 11 clients after migration

Tags: javascript, session-variables

I'm responsible for an internal web application that has been running behind our firewall for at least the past 6 years. Recently a small group of users were migrated to IE 11, while a majority of the Dept has not been yet.  Since the migration a couple of users have been dropping Session variables when a javascript call is made to a new page within the app.  My team and I are trying to lock down the cause, as this only pops up intermittently for a couple of users that, until the migration, had not ad any issues in this section of the application.

Any suggestions on where to go?

Thanks, 
Andrew
Note: I did not write the original code, and it looks like there have been some other hands in it going back to the early version of the AjaxToolkit

Comment: What are "session variables"? These are not part of JavaScript. ASP.NET Session variables? Other?

Comment: Code, please. We need more information.

Comment: the asp.net [webforms] AjaxControlToolkit?

Comment: Try to use IE11 with a previous user agent string, like IE8. There's a known problem with ASP.NET browser definition file and it seems to affect cookie management.

Comment: Additional details: On the Session variables, the application loads as many as 25 different user level values into the HttpSession (so, yes the ASP.Net Session, and hence, the ASP.Net AjaxToolkit that was initially put together for WebForms before the advent of the 2.0 version of the .NET framework).  In two separate pages, the user is provided with a link that uses the javascript "window.open();" with a new page as the destination url. when the user get's there, the HttpSession is checked for a specific value, and it is gone. For the User agent, the app forces IE7 via meta tag in the head.